# Bootcamp won't run on OSX in RAID0

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, mac-pro, raid

I have my MacPro booting into Lion off a 3 disk (software) RAID 0 array. I want to dedicate a fourth drive to Windows 7 via Bootcamp. However it won't run at all on my system, exiting with a 'RAID is not supported' message.

Is there a way around this? Or a reliable, easy-to-use third-party bootloader like `grub` or similar I can use to set-up a dual-boot?

Answer (score 1):

Preliminarily, these guides may help:

http://alexgarlock.com/macbook-pro-2011-raid-0-with-bootcamp/

http://huguesval.com/blog/2012/02/installing-windows-7-on-a-mac-without-superdrive-with-virtualbox/

Read the top one first - and yes I know it's a bit confusing the way he writes it (it doesn't make complete sense to me either, but at least points in some direction).  And yes, they don't completely answer your specific question, but they do provide helpful guidance in the form of pointing you towards the right direction...and perhaps a bit more.

***Actually***, I'm just about to try all this in a few minutes - I'll try to relay the outcome.

Then, if I get bootcamp to work in RAID-0 mode...the final challenge is hacking the EFI boot that your Bootcamped windows is stuck with - so I can emulate a bios setting in the EFI that allows me to switch to AHCI mode in bootcamp.  I've successfully done this before, and it turned bootcamp into a POWERHOUSE.  The difference was sickening.

If any users are interested in also doing the above I suggest you start here and read as much of the thread as you can.

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/126089-howto-boot-macs-with-intel-chipset-in-ahci-win7-vista-xp-linux/page-7#entry1498839

Assuming I get there...the tricky part will genuinely be stacking both of these ridiculous things simultaneously.

I havn't yet found anything anywhere that addresses or even mentions my above proposed "bootcamp-super-stack" about stacking a RAID-0 running in AHCI mode in Bootcamp.

Let's see how this adventure turns out.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this, as I have the same problem.

What if you created 3 partitions when setting up your machine? One for OS X, one for the recovery partition and one for Windows...?

You'd have to slice each hard drive into 3 and then create each RAID separately, but it might work.

The only way I've solved this is to run Parallels and install windows on an external FireWire drive.